# facebook php sdk - getSessionFromRedirect() state doesnt match

Tags: php, facebook

I've had an app using the facebook php sdk for some time now - i 'Upgraded' to the 4.0 SDK perhaps 6 weeks ago.. and my login code has been working fine for the past month  (combo of FacebookRedirectLoginHelper and FacebookJavascriptHelper)

Since yesterday, I'm unable to do a facebook login and get a valid FacebookSession.  I had made no changes to the code at all from the point where it was working fine one day, and then no longer working.

My facebook login code is below.  After some digging/debugging through the FB PHP SDK,  I've determined that the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->isValidRedirect() function is returning null/false on this check:

```
return $this->getCode() && isset($_GET['state']) && $_GET['state'] == $this->state;
```

$_GET['state']  does not match  $this->state

The state that gets generated when I call FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getLoginURL() is getting passed back to my redirect URL by facebook - But for some reason, the php SDK seems to be creating a new state by the time I get to calling getSessionFromRedirect()

I'm not calling getLoginURL() until after the call to getSessionFromRedirect() - so I dont know where or why else the SDK is re-setting the state.  And like I mentioned, this code was working perfectly up until 2 days ago - I hadn't changed anything, it just stopped working from one day to the next.

If I comment out the check for the state within FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->isValidRedirect()  ( ..  && $_GET['state'] == $this->state)  -- then everything works fine.  But I dont want to do that, since I believe that check is there for guarding against CSRF;  and I don't know what other un-intended consequences that change might have.

Here's my code for handling fb sessions (this is run on each page-load)

```
  /**
   * Initialize the Facebook PHP SDK 4
   */

  FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( CL_FB_APP_ID, CL_FB_APP_SECRET);

  $facebookLoginHelper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(CLADDR);
  $facebookJavascriptLoginHelper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();

  $facebookSession= null;
  // see if we've previously saved a facebook session token
  if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // create new fb session object from saved access_token
    cldbgmsg("Found fb_token in session");
    $facebookSession = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

    // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
    try {
      if ( !$facebookSession->validate() ) {
        cldbgmsg("fb_token in session no longer valid");
        $facebookSession = null;
      }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
      // catch any exceptions, nullify the session variable if encountered
      cldbgmsg("Exception validating fb_token found in session" . $e);
      $facebookSession = null;
    }
  }  

  //We didnt find a previously saved session token, so check to see if this is a new 
  //facebook login 
  if ( !isset( $facebookSession ) || $facebookSession === null ) {
    try {
      //Check for a new sessions coming from a redirect
      cldbgmsg("Checking for new facebook session from redirect");
      $facebookSession = $facebookLoginHelper->getSessionFromRedirect();
      //echo "facebooksession from redirect:"; echo "<pre>"; var_dump($facebookSession); echo "</pre>";
      if($facebookSession) cldbgmsg("Found new facebook session from redirect");
      //If no new session from redirect, see if there is a new session set on the client side 
      //  via facebook javascript SDK
      if($facebookSession === null) {
          cldbgmsg("checking for new facebook session from javascript SDK");
          $facebookJavascriptLoginHelper->getSession();
          if($facebookSession) cldbgmsg("Found new facebook session from Javascript SDK");
      }

    } catch( Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException $ex ) {

      //Auth Code expired, so nullify the facebooksession and delete the stored token
      echo "FacebookAuthorizationException getting session in init_facebook";
      //echo "<pre>"; var_dump($ex); echo "</pre>";
      $facebookSession = null;
      $_SESSION['fb_token'] = null;
      //die;
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
      echo "FacebookRequestException getting session in init_facebook";
      echo "<pre>"; var_dump($ex); echo "</pre>";
      die;
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo "Exception getting session in init_facebook";
      echo "<pre>"; var_dump($ex); echo "</pre>";
      die;
    }

  }   

  //If we still dont have a facebook session, generate a login URL that can be used where needed
  if(! $facebookSession){
    cldbgmsg(" no fb session: generating url");
    //Get the login URL - 
    $talentLoginURL = $facebookLoginHelper->getLoginUrl($talentFacebookPermissionScope);

  }
```